# Issues with SAMBA starting, stopping and restarting on CentOS 7.0

Tags: centos, samba

I’ve installed SAMBA on CentOS 7.0 (recently updated) using `yum install`, and when trying start, restart or stop system returns following type of message:

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop smb.service

After I issued the commands I’ve [found here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-samba-startstop.html):

```
/sbin/service smb stop
```

When I grep `smbd` from `ps` output there are two lines with `smbd` and they do not change after issuing stop or restart. So I suppose there is something wrong. I’ve reinstalled SAMBA package but result is the same. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try issuing those same commands [outlined on to page you linked to](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-samba-startstop.html) using `sudo` like this;

```
sudo /sbin/service smb start

sudo /sbin/service smb stop

sudo /sbin/service smb restart
```

But the `/sbin/service` path seems to literal to me and my understanding of how system services work so I would recommend using the far more common—and simpler—way to call service like this:

```
sudo service smb start

sudo service smb stop

sudo service smb restart
```

Or perhaps run it via `systemctl` like this:

```
sudo systemctl start smb.service

sudo systemctl stop smb.service

sudo systemctl restart smb.service
```

Comment: Only issuing systemctl option did work. All others didn't.